# Is there a way for Jenkins to keep track of the reasons of failed builds?

Tags: jenkins

Looking for a way to keep a history and trace back to the original build that failed with a given error.

i.e. build "foo" first failed on #X with error "bar"

Is that built-in Jenkins or a plugin that does it?

Comment: I don't think it does exactly this, but the Build Failure Analyser is a good plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer

Comment: If you are talking about a build failure as opposed to a test failure, see the Build Failure Analyzer.  Tracking of test failures to original build is built into Jenkins.